# adduser causes strange messages when called from preinst script

Tags: scripts, deb, adduser

I have a .deb package in which I have a preinst script that executes the adduser program in case a certain user is not already present on the system.

```
$(id -u {username} > /dev/null 2>&1)
if [ $? -eq 1 ];
then
    echo "Adding user"
    $(adduser --group {groupname})
    $(adduser --disabled-password --ingroup {groupname} --no-create-home --system {username})
fi
exit 0
```

When the preinst script is being run as part of the installation process, the user and group is created like it should, but I see the following strange output lines coming from the adduser command:

```
Adding user
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: Adding: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: Adding: not found
```

What do these lines mean and is it something I should solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did `$(adduser ..)` instead of simply `adduser ..`, you apply [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and that line is replaced with the output of that command. So if `adduser` produces an output of `Adding user ...`, then the shell will try to execute `Adding user ...` as a command. Instead, do:

```bsh
id -u ${username} > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 1 ];
then
    echo "Adding user"
    adduser --group ${groupname}
    adduser --disabled-password --ingroup ${groupname} --no-create-home --system ${username}
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: I always seem to forget command substitution...